# Processing fails with MDX Script error

Tags: mdx

I have the expression in MDX

```
    Filter
    (
      {
        [ ORDER ACTUAL].[Actual  Hours Flag].&[Y]
       ,[MAINT  D].[Preventive  Flag].&[Y]
      }
     ,[Measures].[No of  Orders]
    )
  / 
    [Measures].[No of  Orders]
* 100
```

I got the following error :

> Processing fails with MDX Script error

Comment: What is your filter condition? The second argument of `Filter` is usually a condition e.g. `color <> Red` or `age > 18` but in your script the second argument just says `[Measures].[No of  Orders]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to use `filter` or are you just after tuples that are not empty? Reason I ask is that the second argument of your filter is not a Boolean condition so I'm guessing you just want non empty tuples which would be the following:

```
    NonEmpty
    (
      (
        [ ORDER ACTUAL].[Actual  Hours Flag].&[Y]
       ,[MAINT  D].[Preventive  Flag].&[Y]
      )
     ,[Measures].[No of  Orders]
    )
  / 
    [Measures].[No of  Orders]
* 100
```

Just in case you need to use the `Filter` function then the syntax is more like the following:

```
Filter
(
  (
    [ ORDER ACTUAL].[Actual  Hours Flag].&[Y]
   ,[MAINT  D].[Preventive  Flag].&[Y]
  )
 ,[Measures].[No of  Orders] > 0  //<<< a Boolean (e.g. =/<>/>/<) condition is here
)
```

/ 
    [Measures].[No of  Orders]
* 100

Comment: (upped) Didn't hit me. Your answer makes sense

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I noticed canada_canada using filter like this in previous posts

Answer (score 2):

One of the closing brace is missing but I am guessing that's not the issue. Considering your expression is:

```
 filter (
 {[ ORDER ACTUAL].[Actual  Hours Flag].&[Y] ,  [MAINT  D].[Preventive  Flag].&[Y]} 
 ,[Measures].[No of  Orders])/[Measures].[No of  Orders]* 100)
```

Your code is failing because you are trying to bunch members of different hierarchies in the same set. **But**, in MDX that's not allowed.  (curly braces, or {} represent a set). What you need is :

```
 filter (
 ([ ORDER ACTUAL].[Actual  Hours Flag].&[Y] ,  [MAINT  D].[Preventive  Flag].&[Y]) 
 ,[Measures].[No of  Orders])/[Measures].[No of  Orders]* 100)
```

That should work.

Comment: I need to remove all } in my query ? there is alredy one in  your query